# SharePoint Designer 2007 / SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, 2007, sharepoint-designer

Can anyone advise if it's possible to run SharePoint Designer 2007 for an on-premise installation and SharePoint Designer 2013 for SP online on the same machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No it will not.
Make sure you have the appropriate version of office installed on the system as well; use the 64-bit version for Office and SharePoint Designer both.